# Probability of a discrete random variable - 68% of movie fans see Black Panther

Tags: probability

68% percent of comic fans visited a movie theater to see Black Panther.
Nine movie viewers are selected at random. Let X be a discrete random variable representing the number of the movie viewers.

1. FindP(X=4),P(X=5) and P(X=6).
2. Write down an expression forF(y) and the cumulative distribution function(CDF) of X, for all y-values from -inf to inf
3. Find the Expected value and Variance of X

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to math.stachexchange; you are more likely to have success with people helping you with problems if you show your attempts at solving the problem, or explain your knowledge of the area before posting.

As it stands, I think you misunderstand the notation/definitions. In your problem statement you say *"nine movie viewers are selected at random"*, and then define $X = \{\text{no. of movie viewers}\}$. As it stands

$$\mathbf P[X \geq 9] = 1$$

and therefore
$$\mathbf{P}[X = 4] = \mathbf{P}[X = 5] = \mathbf{P}[X = 6] = 0.$$

The follow up questions also have simple answers for this problem description.

I think therefore (and I am guessing) that the problem you want to solve is most likely: *"68% of visitors to a cinema see Black Pantha. Nine movie viewers are selected at random, and let $X$ denote the number who watched Black Pantha."*

In this context, as a hint you will want to look at properties of [Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) random variables.